# Does quartz create a separate threadpool for different quartz instances?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a situation where we have multiple quartz schedulers. Actually I am using a third party jar file which is using quartz scheduler and I am also using quartz scheduler in my application. The quartz.configuration file looks alike as below:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Our application gets scheduler instance by using StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler("MyScheduler") API call. The third party people use StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler() API call to create their scheduler instance. I just wanted to know if both of these schedulers will be sharing same thread pool or different thread pools will be created for each of respective schedulers.

Answer (score 0):

No, as long as those are different scheduler instances, they will be using different thread pools.

And this can be verified by running a unit test initializing two schedulers, like:

```
@Test
void quartzTest() throws SchedulerException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty(StdSchedulerFactory.PROP_SCHED_INSTANCE_NAME, "MyScheduler");
    prop.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "10");
    Scheduler s1 = new StdSchedulerFactory(prop).getScheduler();
    Scheduler s2 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
}
```